# CRM Dynamics: how to get viewname in record list using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm searching to get the name of the current view of a record list. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName()

See the Client Side API Documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328255.aspx

Comment: Xrm.Page.data is not available in a record list (note that by "record list" I don't mean a subgrid in an entity form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below script to get the view name from ribbon:

```
var viewName = '';
if (crmGrid && crmGrid.control) {
viewName = crmGrid.control.get_viewTitle();
}
```

[Reference](https://rajeevpentyala.com/tag/crmgrid/)

Update:

I don't see a supported way to do it. But there are some **unsupported** [solution](https://mahadeomatre.blogspot.my/2015/04/hide-ribbon-button-based-on-view.html) (may be only way, I haven't tested it personally)

```
function HideButtonBasedOnViewSelected (selectedCtrl) {             
        var query = selectedCtrl.get_viewTitle();
        if (query == 'Your View Name') {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

> Add Crm parameter, and set parameter value as SelectedControl
>   To get selected view name need to use some unsupported JavaScript.

[Community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/268358)

Comment: crmGrid is undefined.

Comment: @Dremor based on your crm version you may need to pass primarycontrol as crm parameter in ribbon & try to consume control from formcontext

Comment: tried primaryControl earlier, result in a null object.